# How to specify twitter bootstrap's <i> tag in Embedded Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

-Newbie to Ruby on Rails and integrating a few aspects of Twitter Bootstrap in (or at least trying :))-

I have a link in regular HTML with Twitter Bootstrap icons in it:

```
   <li class="sidebar"><a href="#"><i class="icon-user"></i> Home</a></li>
```

(The i tag is for twitter's image icons)

If I were writing that same HTML in embedded Ruby, how could I still get the icon in there?

Right now I have:

```
   <%= link_to content_tag(:li, "Home"), root_path %>
```

Is it possible to specify Twitter's  tag in embedded ruby?

Also, should I specify the sidebar class in regular html or with  :class => "sidebar"

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, just try something like:

```
<%= content_tag(:li, :class => 'sidebar') do %>
  <%= link_to '#' do %>
    <%= content_tag :i, '', :class => 'icon-user' %> Home
  <% end -%>
<% end -%>
```

Answer (score 1):

The shorter alternative I use is

link_to " ".html_safe, '#'

It's 'dirtier' but somewhat easier to understand.